# Fix with ulimit -n 8192

Tags: linux, caddy

Running `caddy` on a linux machine, and I receive the following error:

```
WARNING: File descriptor limit 1024 is too low for production servers.
         At least 8192 is recommended. 

         Fix with "ulimit -n 8192"
```

Ok, great.  But where do I fix it?

Comment: `ulimit -n 8192`

Comment: @RehanAzher yeah but where?

Comment: http://landoflinux.com/linux_ulimit_command.html

Comment: ulimit is a command , u just need to run this on terminal

Comment: This question would be better-suited to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com).

Comment: @RehanAzher, if you have an answer, put it as an answer rather than a series of context-free comments. Also I'm sure the OP wants something permanent; clearly they know the command that needs to be run already.

Comment: @JimStewart thanks man.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

For a temporary fix, you can simply issue the command `ulimit -n 8192`.

For permanent you need to modify `/etc/security/limits.conf`.

For more details please refer below:

https://singztechmusings.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/ulimit-how-to-permanently-set-kernel-limits-in-linux/

From article:

> `vi /etc/security/limits.conf`
>
> Add two lines for each limit:
>
> `* soft nofile 16384`
>   `* hard nofile 16384`

Comment: And I recommend raising the NOFILES limit (ulimit -n) as high as you can, if your web server is the only primary purpose of the machine; you might as well, to make sure traffic spikes don't take you down.